# merge two files in shell like paste command

Tags: linux, shell

```
>cat tmp1

1

2

3

>cat tmp2

vol1

vol2
```

expecting this answer

```
vol1 1

vol1 2

vol1 3

vol2 1

vol2 2

vol2 3
```

Comment: please format your question properly, check [ask] and show your efforts.

Comment: This is not like the `paste` command at all...

Answer (score 1):

If order of the lines is not so important

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{for(i in a){print $0,i}}' tmp2 tmp1
```

If you want to restore the  order:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;l=FNR;next}{for(i=1;i<=l;i++){print $0,a[i]}}' tmp2 tmp1
```

Comment: I don't know why you're suggesting `nawk` specifically; this should work in any version. You can use `a[++n] = $0` in the first block to keep track of the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ while read a; do while read b; do echo $a $b; done<tmp1; done<tmp2
vol1 1
vol1 2
vol1 3
vol2 1
vol2 2
vol2 3
```

Or with a nicer indentation:

```
while read a; do
    while read b; do
        echo $a $b
    done <tmp1
done <tmp2
```

For each word in the `tmp2` file, echo it followed by each word in the `tmp1` file.

If the *actual* data in the two files contains backslashes, or if the `tmp2` file contains dashes in the first column, then the following will be a better and more robust solution:

```
while read -r a; do
    while read -r b; do
        printf '%s %s\n' "$a" "$b"
    done <tmp1
done <tmp2
```

Comment: I'd suggest always using `read -r` and quoting your variables. Also, consider using `printf '%s %s\n' "$a" "$b"`.

Comment: @TomFenech You're right, but we were given a specific set of data. I will however update the answer.

Comment: @TomFenech What's the benefit of using printf in this case? An also, since it doesn't matter if the variables contain spaces, quoting is strictly speaking unnecessary, in this case.

Comment: There's not really any disadvantage to using `read -r` or quoting variables, so I'd recommend doing both things all the time, as it makes scripts more robust. The benefit of using `printf` is that you don't run into problems when `$a` is `-e`, for example (again, I know that the data shown here is fine but it's a question of recommending the most robust approach).

Comment: @TomFenech Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to do,

```
for file in `cat tmp1` 
do
        for f in `cat tmp2`
        do
                echo $file $f
        done
done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also, in general it's better to use a tool for text processing.